# References for better performance of newer JSF specifications

Tags: performance, jsf, reference

I'm looking for a reference to cite, which states that JSF 1.2 performs better than JSF 1.1. Or JSF 2.0 over JSF 1.2 respectively.

I'm quite sure that I've read something like this before but can't find it anymore.
Maybe you can help. Or is this mischief and there are no official statements regarding the performance?

Comment: http://www.laliluna.de/articles/jsf-2-evaluation-test.html

Answer (score 1):

I bet that you're talking about the Mojarra implementation (formerly known as Sun RI) since "JSF" is an abstract specification.

If you check the changelogs of Mojarra 1.2, you'll see that **a lot** of improvements/enhancements have been made with regard to performance. RI 1.0/1.1 was relatively poor in this and with JSF 1.2 they brought some new and talented developers in the team, under each Ryan Lubke who has its focus set on performance enhancements. You can find all 1.2 changelogs at the bottom of the release note of the latest version, such as [1.2_14](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/rlnotes/1.2_14/releasenotes.html). Note the `ENHANCEMENT` fixes, most of them are performance targeted.

Mojarra 2.0 is just a newer version against a more enriched specification with code which is already written with performance in mind by the same team.

Comment: Great! This really gives me something to start with. Thanks a lot. But are there any statements regarding JSF in general? E.g. that JSF 2.0 performs better >>by design<<? I mean, have look on JSF 1.1 although it's just an abstract standard it is however addressed to bugfixes. Is this transferable to performance statements?